# Code Coverage - SalesForce Bug

Tags: force.com, administration, code-coverage, isv

While trying to upload our package (as an ISV partner) I noticed the following readings:

- Upload failed due to 73% code coverage (of course... we need 75%)
  [image]
- From the "Apex Classes" screen, after asking to calculate/estimate code coverage I get "Code Coverage: 61%"

[image]

- And after running all tests in the developer console, I see that
  I have a code coverage of 76% which should allow me to upload

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are all the Apex Classes and Triggers included in the managed package?

Comment: Of course :) it's like that for a few years

Comment: What happens to the overall code coverage reported by the developer console if you clear all the previous test results (coverage should go to 0%) and then run all the tests that are included in the managed package again. Probably the easiest course of action is just to increase your code coverage for the largest classes. This will have a meaningful benefit in the long run as well.

Comment: It is marked as fixed in Spring 15. But the following known issue may be applicable: [Code coverage inconsistency between deployments and "Estimate your organization's code coverage"](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T5k3AAC)

Comment: There is also [Updating an Apex class through Metadata API makes its code coverage corrupt](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XbVAAU) which is scheduled for a fix in a Summer 15 patch. Try deleting the stored ApexCodeCoverageAggregate records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had a very similar issue. I had a small Apex class where I was certain the code coverage was at, or at least very close to, 100%.

However, the developer console was reporting that it had only 60% coverage. Also, the code coverage lines weren't lining up in a meaningful way with the actual body of the Apex class. It was showing coverage over comment lines and nothing for several of the later lines in the class.

This lined up with the symptoms of the known issue [Updating an Apex class through Metadata API makes its code coverage corrupt](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XbVAAU). After I deleted the ApexCodeCoverageAggregate records in the org and reran the tests the code coverage successfully reset to 100%.

So I'd suggest deleting those records and running all the tests again. It is likely that the process creating the managed package is independent of the ApexCodeCoverageAggregate records.

In addition to the known issue above this is also the knowledge article: [Code coverage steps and considerations prior to deployments](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Code-coverage-steps-and-considerations-prior-to-deployments&language=en_US). This also covers deleting the ApexCodeCoverageAggregate records.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, although I am not updating apex classes through metadata API , I am using online editing (using SalesFoce Dev Env.) to update apex classes or any other entity (trigger/page etc)

Comment: @Uri Did clearing the `ApexCodeCoverageAggregate` records using the tooling API before running the tests resolve the issue?