# Getting Zero code coverage for trigger

Tags: trigger, code-coverage

Test runs successfully but showing the code coverage as zero. please help.!

```
trigger AddCampaignMembers on Lead (after insert, after update) {
system.debug('In the trigger');
Lead[] leads = trigger.new;

/* populate complete lead details */
List<Lead> currentLeadDtls = [Select Id, Name, Owner.Id, Main_Campaign__c from lead where Id in:leads];    

/* create a "set of campaigns" and a "Map of campaign to lead" */
Set<ID> campaigns = new Set<Id>();
for (Lead l : currentLeadDtls) {
    if(l.Main_Campaign__c != null){
        campaigns.add(l.Main_Campaign__c);
    }
}

/* get all the existing leads - campaignMembers */    
List<CampaignMember> CampaignMembers = [Select CampaignId, LeadId from CampaignMember where CampaignId in:campaigns];

/* key: campaign; value: Set of Lead Ids */
Map<Id, Set<Id>> oldCampaignMemberMap = new Map<Id, Set<Id>>();
Set<Id> tempLeadIds = null;
for(CampaignMember cm : CampaignMembers){
    if(oldCampaignMemberMap.containsKey(cm.CampaignId)){
        tempLeadIds = oldCampaignMemberMap.get(cm.CampaignId);
        tempLeadIds.add(cm.LeadId);
    }else{
        tempLeadIds = new Set<Id>();
        tempLeadIds.add(cm.LeadId);
        oldCampaignMemberMap.put(cm.CampaignId, tempLeadIds);
    }        
}

Lead[] newLeads = new List<Lead>();
CampaignMember[] newCampaignMembers = new List<CampaignMember>();

for(Lead l : currentLeadDtls){
    if(l.Main_Campaign__c != null){
        //To add the lead as Campaign member 
        if(oldCampaignMemberMap.containsKey(l.Main_Campaign__c)){
            tempLeadIds = oldCampaignMemberMap.get(l.Main_Campaign__c);
            if(tempLeadIds == null || !tempLeadIds.contains(l.id)){
                CampaignMember tempCM = new CampaignMember();
                tempCM.LeadId = l.Id;
                tempCM.CampaignId = l.Main_Campaign__c;
                newCampaignMembers.add(tempCM);
           }
        }else{
            CampaignMember tempCM = new CampaignMember();
            tempCM.LeadId = l.Id;
            tempCM.CampaignId = l.Main_Campaign__c;
            newCampaignMembers.add(tempCM);
        }

    }
}

if(!newCampaignMembers.isEmpty())
    insert newCampaignMembers;

system.debug('out of the trigger');
```

}

```
@isTest
public class TestAddCampaignMembersTrigger {

    public static testMethod void testRunAs() {

        Campaign testCamp = createCampaign();
        insert testCamp;
        Lead testLead = createLead();

        Test.startTest();
            insert testLead;
            testLead.Main_Campaign__c = testCamp.Id;
            update testLead;

            /* Check for campaign members */
            List<CampaignMember> CampaignMembers = [Select CampaignId, LeadId from CampaignMember where CampaignId = :testCamp.Id ];
            Boolean check = false;
            for(CampaignMember cm : CampaignMembers){
                if(cm.LeadId == testLead.Id){
                    check = true;
                }
            }
            system.assertEquals(true, check);
        Test.stopTest();        
    }

    public static Campaign createCampaign(){
        Campaign testCamp = new Campaign();
        testCamp.Name = 'testCamp';
        testCamp.isActive = true;
        return testCamp;
    }

    public static Lead createLead(){
        Lead testLead = new Lead();
        testLead.lastName = 'testLastName';
        testLead.Company = 'testcompany';
        return testLead;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you post the trigger code as well?

Comment: In all probability, it's probably just a glitch. Try clearing your coverage and then running all tests. See, by way of example, http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/73575/ and http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/81297/ for two related questions that *may* help you.

Comment: Having just refreshed and looked at your trigger code, I can guarantee that your coverage is not 0% if the test is running successfully. Try clearing your cache and running all your tests from scratch. See above linked questions on how to do this.

Comment: Cleared the cache as mentioned in the post, but still no luck.. Getting 0% coverage!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently had the same problem, and as far as I could tell it came down to a bug related to running tests from the Developer Console. Try this work around: run the tests from the main interface by going to Setup > Develop > Apex Test Execution and run your test from there. If you are having the same issue I was seeing, you should see the correct test coverage when done that way.

EDIT: Its a known issue: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000eMoyAAE

> **Winter '16 - In Developer Console, running tests synchronously does not generate code coverage**
>   Apex , Developer Console , Winter 16
>
> **Summary**
>   In Winter '16, Salesforce introduced a new option under the
>   'Test' tab in the Developer Console called 'Always Run
>   Asynchronously'. By default, this option is unchecked which will in
>   turn run tests synchronously.
>
> Presently, in Winter '16 orgs, when we run tests synchronously via the
>   Developer Console, we observe no code coverage is calculated. Further,
>   when we query the objects 'ApexCodeCoverage' and
>   'ApexCodeCoverageAggregate' via Tooling API, we observe no results for
>   the class being tested.
>
> Repro
>   1. In a Winter '16 org, create a new trigger as follows using any API version:

```
trigger codeCoverageTrigger on Case (before insert) { 
    for (Case c: Trigger.new)  {  
        c.Subject='TEST CASE for code coverage';
        c.description = 'Hello World';  
    }
}
```

> 2. Create a test class for the trigger to generate code coverage as follows:

```
@isTest  public class codeCoverageTrigger_Test { 
    static testMethod void insertCase() {
        Case testCase = new Case(); 
        testCase.Origin='Web';  
        testCase.Status='New';  
        insert testCase ;
    } 
}
```

> 3. Open Developer Console and examine the 'Test' tab, observe the option 'Always Run Asynchronously'. In Winter '16 orgs, this option is
>      unchecked by default which will in turn run tests synchronously. For
>      this repro, leave it unchecked.
> 4. In Developer Console, open the test class 'codeCoverageTrigger_Test' (Developer Console->File->Open->Classes)
>      and click 'Run Test'
> 5. You can monitor the test run via 'Apex Test Execution' section(Setup->Develop->Apex Test Execution), once complete open the
>      trigger 'codeCoverageTrigger'
> 6. Observe the code coverage for the trigger is 0%, if we further examine the code coverage breakdown via Developer Console or by
>      querying the objects 'ApexCodeCoverage' and
>      'ApexCodeCoverageAggregate' via Tooling API, we will observe no
>      coverage is generated for the trigger

### Workaround:

> Workaround In Winter '16 orgs, if we check the option 'Always Run
>   Asynchronously' under the 'Test' tab and re-run the test class via
>   Developer Console, code coverage will be generated as expected.
>
> Alternatively, if the tests are ran via the UI, code coverage is
>   generated as expected.